# Replace NULL with 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-null

I have the following `CASE` expression that separates data into different categories and attach corresponding hours.

```
case
when Wstat_Name_Ch like '%Overtime signup%' then payhours
end as All_OT_Signup,
case
when  Wstat_Abrv_Ch in ('CO', 'COU', 'Otnoshow') then payhours
end as OT_Removed,
case
when  Wstat_Abrv_Ch in ('Ov', 'OTField', 'MinStafotp', 'OvUpsOT') then payhours
end as OT_Hours_Worked
```

The statement returns data like this:

```
All_OT_Signup    OT_Removed   OT_Hours_Worked
500.00            NULL         NULL
350.00            150.00       100.00
200.00            NULL         NULL
```

what I need to do is replace any NULL with 0. I tried `ISNULL(payhours, 0)` in place of payhours, but it did not work.

Comment: Hint:  `ELSE` for the `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an `else` branch to each `case` expression, that returns `0` when the first condition does not match:

```sql
case
    when Wstat_Name_Ch like '%Overtime signup%' then payhours
    else 0
end as All_OT_Signup,
case
    when  Wstat_Abrv_Ch in ('CO', 'COU', 'Otnoshow') then payhours
    else 0
end as OT_Removed,
case
    when  Wstat_Abrv_Ch in ('Ov', 'OTField', 'MinStafotp', 'OvUpsOT') then payhours
    else 0
end as OT_Hours_Worked
```